# Can I force a user to provide a value for a member when using designated initializers?

Tags: c++, initialization, designated-initializer

I have created an options struct, intended to be used via designated initializer:

```
struct FooOptions {
    bool enableReticulation;
};

void Foo(FooOptions&& opts);

Foo(FooOptions{.enableReticulation = true});
```

Unfortunately, because `bool` has a default constructor, it's also valid to do this:

```
Foo(FooOptions{});
```

but I don't want this; I want users of Foo to explicitly decide to enable reticulation or not. I can achieve this with a runtime error this way:

```
struct FooOptions {
    bool enableReticulation = []() -> bool { 
        assert(false, "No value provided for enableReticulation");
    }();
};
```

But I would prefer to do this with a compile time error. Is there any way to do that? I am OK with changing `bool` to `SomeWrapper<bool>` if necessary, as long I can mostly initialize `SomeWrapper<T>` as if it were `T`, but without a default initializer.

Comment: Sure, that's exactly how you to do this, by using a wrapper type with a non-default constructor. As Capt. Jean-Luc Picard would say: make it so.

Comment: The problem is that I would like the `SomeWrapper<T>` to be constructible in all the ways `T` can be constructed, _except_ default constructed. For simple types like `bool` this is easy, but if I have `SomeWrapper<std::vector<int>>`, I want to be able to initialize with `std::initializer_list<int>`, a pair of iterators, an allocator, and all the other ways a `std::vector` can be initialized.

Comment: You can use a variadic template for the second argument on and perfect-forward all the arguments

Comment: So? Either a delegate the constructor, and explicitly `delete` the default constructor, or use a forwarding constructor with at least one parameter.

Comment: I have tried a few things along those lines with no success :( I either get multiple overloads resolving to the same type, which is not valid, or I end up with the wrapper still being default constructible, for empty parameter pack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Way to handle classes and non-classes types, thank to SFINAE:

```
template<typename T, typename Enabler = void> class TWrapper;

template<typename T>
class TWrapper<T, std::enable_if_t<std::is_class<T>::value>> : public T {
public:
    TWrapper()=delete;

    using T::T;
};

template<typename T>
class TWrapper<T, std::enable_if_t<!std::is_class<T>::value>>
{
public:
    TWrapper()=delete;

    T value;
    TWrapper(T arg) : value(arg) {}
    operator T() const { return value; }
};
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/01e1b3622a8efcbd)

Answer (score 2):

You clarified that this is about arbitrary classes, and not primitive types. For arbitrary classes, with arbitrary constructors: just delete the constructor, but explicitly `delete` the default constructor:

```
template<typename T> class SomeWrapper : public T {

    SomeWrapper()=delete;

    using T::T;
};
```

Then:

```
#include <vector>

foo F{ {1,2} }; // Works, initializes the vector with {1,2}

foo G{}; // Fails
```

This may not work like you want for primitive types. Just specialize `SomeWrapper` as needed. There aren't that many primitive types to deal with.

Comment: Thanks! Fortunately in my case I only care about `bool`, `int`, `float`, and `double` for primitive types, so this works great. I didn't even think about using inheritance.